# Changed the password start getting "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized" error

Tags: .net, web-services, security

I have a remoting service which uses the Windows Auth. Been working fine for a while but yesterday my windows account has been lockout and after it has been unlocked and the password changed I have been having issues since.

It just didn't let me in with the following error:

"System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

May be my old password / credentials somehow stuck in a credential cache in my local PC or something like that.

Any ideas how to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using on the client side?  A web browser?  The browser SHOULD handle the 401 by displaying a dialog box for you to type in the correct username and password.

If the problem is because of something cached on the local PC, can you try it from a different computer?

Comment: I don't use browser - have a client applicaiton.
I found the culprit. The credentials do actually cache when windows ask for a username first time it accesses the network resource (e.g. a network share). After I restarted my computer and it tried to connect to network share it poped up the dialog box you mentioned and after I specified the new password - the problem has disappeared.